# How RiotJs can get the value of all the checkbox with the same name/id in a form?

Tags: javascript, html, riot.js

I have a multicheckbox list which I would like to get all the value for the selected ones. How can I do that with RiotJs?

I can do it with vanilla javascript using the next intruction: `document.forms['FormName'].elements['checkBoxName'];`

Comment: Can you post the markup for your tag?

Comment: Sure I can, here is the form code:
<form>
   <div>
      <input id="extraField" name="extraField" class="check" type="checkbox" ref="extraField" value="1">Hydraulic steering </input>
      <input id="extraField" name="extraField" class="check" type="checkbox" ref="extraField" value="2">Central locking </input>
      <input id="extraField" name="extraField" class="check" type="checkbox" ref="extraField" value="3">Power seats </input>
   </div>
</form>

Answer (score 0):

You can use ref to get the reference to the form and then just vanilla JS.
There are not advanced dom selectors in Riot.

```
<my-tag>
  <form ref='form'>
    <span each={ items }>
      <input type="checkbox" value="{value}" checked="{ checked }">{name}</input> 
    </span>
    <input type="button" value="submit "onclick={ submit }>
  </form>  
  <script>
    this.items =[{name:'Central locking', checked:false},{name:'Power seats', checked:false}] 
    submit(e) {
      console.log(this.refs.form.elements)
    }
  </script>
</my-tag>
```

Online version http://plnkr.co/edit/xwWCcwAQG2IhvJuQA7Yz

Also you could change your approach and do it programmatically. Adding an onclick when the user click the checkbox, and save that state in a hash or something so you can maintain the state of the form.